# How put inner class into Apex enterprise Pattern Service layer?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, pattern

I need use structure (or wrapper class) in Apex Enterprise Pattern.

```
public with sharing class Structure {
        
    public String name { get; set;}
    public Integer limit {get; set;}
    private void methodName(){
        this.name = SelectorLayerName.selectByLimit(this.limit);
}
```

When I use method from this class

```
private void methodName(){
    this.name = SelectorLayerName.selectByLimit(this.limit);
}
```

I have an error

```
Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: List<sObjectName> SObjectNameSelector.selectByLimit(Integer)
```

Selector layer method is down.

**query from SObjectNameSelector**

```
public List<sObjectName> selectByLimit (Integer limit){
        fflib_QueryFactory sObjectNamesQueryFactory = newQueryFactory();
        return (List<sObjectName>) Database.query(
            sObjectNamesQueryFactory 
            .selectFields(new List<String>{'Id'})
            .setLimit(limit)
            .toSOQL()
        );
        //must return 
        //List<sObjectName> listSON = [SELECT Id FROM sObjectName LIMIT :limit]
    }
```

How can I use this helper class in my layers or do I need create it as Apex Class and that's it?
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to make instance of `SObjectNameSelector` class (so the method `selectByLimit` will not be executed in a static context):

```
private void methodName(){
    SelectorLayerName tmp = new SelectorLayerName();
    this.name = tmp.selectByLimit(this.limit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mariia Illarionova for your response, but I tried to do this and caught the same error `Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: fflib_QueryFactory fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory()`. This method got from fflib library so I can't change it

Comment: @oldgunner newQueryFactory() should be static, too.

Comment: this method is in Apex Enterprise Pattern library files. Should I change it in my org? I think I can't.

Comment: @oldgunner I have changed the approach and updated the answer. Please, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If using the fflib-recommended `Application` class which provides a factory for creating selector, domain, unit of work, and service layer objects, the pattern would be (assuming a selector on Account):

```
private void methodName(){
    Account[] accounts = AccountsSelector.newInstance().selectByLimit(this.limit);
}
```

If not using the fflib-recommended `Application` class

```
private void methodName(){
    Account[] accounts = 
      new AccountsSelector().selectByLimit(this.limit);
}
```